# on any or no provocation

Tags: meaning-in-context

*Webster Thayer remained on the Superior Court bench and continued
hearing cases. It “was frequently reported that he would begin to talk about
the [Sacco-Vanzetti] case to his personal friends, and even to strangers, **on any or no provocation**.*

I am not sure what the passage in bold exactly means. Does it tell that Thayer started talking about the case willingly and that no one did not have to force him to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have it basically correct.  You can think of it as "Thayer would start talking about the case on any provocation" (that is, if he had *any* excuse to start talking about it) or even on *no* provocation (that is, even if there was no particular reason).